# Editing bash $PATH

Tags: bash, osx, path

I want to edit my bash $PATH globally for all shells. I was told that I could add/remove stuff from my .bash_profile or .bashrc to do this, but when I look in these files, they are missing folders that I see when i

```
echo $PATH
```

Is there a way to edit the $PATH globally for all shell sessions from the terminal itself? Or is there another way to configure this? 
This is my path:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/users/developer/desktop/stack/3.dev-ops/build-test-deploy/front-end-package-manager/composer/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS:/Applications/Xamarin Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin
```

I am trying to remove this:

```
/users/developer/desktop/stack/3.dev-ops/build-test-deploy/front-end-package-manager/composer/bin
```

Comment: What do you mean for "all shells"? Bash is your shell. If you want to edit your path for other shells like CSH or ZSH then you'll need to modify the environment variables specific to those shells.

Comment: I meant for every time I open iterm2.

Comment: or terminal.app for that matter.

Comment: Are you running iterm as the root user? To find out: execute `whoami` at the iterm prompt.

Comment: no I am running it as developer or home

Comment: Then, it is odd to have the `/usr/sbin` and `/sbin` directories in the PATH as a normal user.

Comment: @Isaac No, they are part of the standard part of `PATH` on e.g. macOS (which I have reason to believe that the user is using).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BASH first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.  After that it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login,  and  ~/.profile  in  that  order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.

So your PATH variable is either being set in `/etc/profile` or from `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login`, or `.profile` from your home directory.

If you want to add or remove directories to your path you should look there. If your path is being set globally from `/etc/profile` I'd recommend setting your custom `PATH` locally in your `~/.bash_profile`. It's better not to change the global `/etc/profile` file.

EDIT:
It looks like you were using macOS so the answer is to edit your `/etc/paths` file and remove the offending directory.

Make sure to explain you're running macOS in future questions to save time, as their configuration is a little different than e.g. Linux.

Comment: what's odd is when I check all of those locations, none of them have that path that I am trying to remove.

Comment: It's being set from somewhere in config file in your home directory, there's no other possibility. Did you try grepping for the path you're looking for?

Comment: no how do I do that?

Comment: the path doesn't exist anymore by the way

Comment: but it is still in my echo $PATH which is strange.

Comment: grep front-end-package-manager ~/.* should find that string in a hidden file in your home directory that is responsible for setting or adding that directory to your path.

Comment: Can I private message you the output from that command?

Comment: Sure yeah, go for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82700/discussion-between-cody-rutscher-and-a-h).

Answer (score 0):

The PATH could be set in any of the various files bash reads when it starts. To find them all, run this in a **new** instance of iterm:

```
grep --color -rlH 'PATH=' \
     ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login \
     ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile \
     /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment \
     ~/.xinitrc ~/.xprofile /etc/xprofile \
     /etc/paths /etc/paths.d/
                        2> /dev/null
```

Those are the standard ones. If you are also sourcing other files from one of those, things can get more complex.

If you find the file setting the PATH variable then you are done and can edit such file. If not, maybe you have removed some packages. What is the reported PATH in a **new** instance of iTerm?